# HylaFax, How to use it from .net application

Tags: .net, fax

I have .net application that sends faxes, I am considering using hylaFAX to send faxes.

I can't find how to call hylafax server from .net. Is there any library or anything i can use to call hylafax from .net?

Answer (score 1):

A bit old but it works for me
http://sourceforge.net/projects/hfc4net/develop

Comment: Looking at utilizing hfc4net right now.  Any insight you can provide @AlexanderN?  Curious to find out if you ran into limitations, etc.

Comment: @Richard B, no limitations so far (using in production). Do keep an eye on active and passive connections due to different network configurations found on clients.

Comment: Awesome.  I've spent the better part of the afternoon on looking into solutions.  Hylafax lists a .Net project that's supposed to be available, but I can't get a link to their Digital River account that works as expected.  Will give this a go in the Morning and see what happens with it... Hoping it works so I can save said client a few grand on deploying Faxcom servers.

Comment: Just did a quick and dirty project in winforms to test the code.  for our needs, seems to have worked like a charm.  Thanks @AlexanderN

Comment: @Richard B, awesome, up voted the question posted by mamu, it seems others may need this.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed and hosted SOAP webservice(written in java & hosted in tomcat using xfire webservices) in the hylafax machine and i called the web service from .net

the web service code will execute command line for hylafax operations, see the partial code. i have done this in past and it worked very well.

```
public class HylaFaxService{

   public String sendFax(String faxno, byte[] bytContent){
       // sendfax -n -d 5551212 -d 5551313 /etc/networktemp/f1.pdf

       // 1. save the bytContent in some temp file say /etc/networktemp/f1.pdf
       // 2. now call the hylafax sendcommand

       Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sendfax -n -d 5551212 -d 5551313 /etc/networktemp/f1.pdf");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HylaFAX is a telecommunication system for UNIX systems.

You can set up Hylafax to accept email to send a fax or set it up as a printer and then you would just print to it.

But it need to run on a Linux/Unix box.  If you have questions check out the hylafax mailing list.  It is a little slow but you will get an answer in a couple of days.